# Searching for SIMS 2 scenario or story download

Tags: the-sims-2

After playing Sims 2 for a while I don't want to play any scenarios already present. You have a scenario where one guy wants to date a woman and succeed in a career as an artist with absolutly 0 skills, a kid who wants to have fun (meaning lots of video games) and top his school(meaning lots of studies), a teenager who wants earn big(meaning lots of work) and get a life partner(meaning lots of social stuff). I don't like these scenarios that came with the game. Each of them has too many characters to focus on and too much variation in what they want to do in life. Its like saying "I want to grow up to be a T-Rex and fly around space". If you have one you can't have the other.

So I'm thinking of downloading custom scenarios from somewhere. I'm not sure what I should be searching for, sims 2 scenarios or families or modifications or sims.

Could someone please point out any website where I can download more stories for sims 2 and also what is the term for the content that am I looking for?

Comment: At first I thought you'd ask for a location to get the game from... Illegally.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that. Thanks for changing the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't download new scenarios for the Sims per se, but you can download pre created Families with goals and wants created by other players. Most of these are available directly on [The Sims 2](http://www.thesims2.com) website. Look under the Exchange section and specifically at Sims.

Alternatively you can look at doing a Sims 2 Challenge. The concept is that there is a specific set of criteria you have to meet with a particular Sim or Sim family, and it adds some goals to playing the actual game. There is a forum dedicated to Sims 2 challenge at Mod The Sims [here](http://www.modthesims.info/forumdisplay.php?f=560). You can also look for downloadable families at Mod The Sims, as they are one of the bigger Sims resources online.

I recently started one with the new Vampires in the Sims 3 based on the Legendary Challenge.